# Computing mod inverse?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How might one compute $4^{-1} \mod 17$ I know the answer is 13. I'm just not sure how to arrive at that number, and can't find any good explanations. Any help would be great

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm $\;$

Comment: What you linked me to is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm which gives the GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) of two numbers, no? It isn't helpful. I'm not looking for the GCD of these two numbers. I'm looking for an example similar to solve $x^{-1} \mod y$

Comment: What I linked you "to is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm which gives the" $\hspace{1.5 in}$ "coefficients of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity)". $\;$

Comment: I'm very confused. I thought it was rather simple to solve the problem I have. Are you saying I need to find the GCD(4,17) first? I just want to be clear

Comment: No, you'll need either x or y, depending on which of {a,b} is to be inverted. $\;$

Comment: So for the extended euclidean algorithm my $x$ would be $4$, my $y$ would be $17$?

Comment: No, your $a$ would be 4 and your $b$ would be 17. $\;$

Comment: Ahh okay. Now I'm getting somewhere. So I need to plug in my $a$ and $b$ into the **Ext Eucl Alg** to get some $s_i$ and $t_i$? Then what is my next step?

Comment: No, your next step is to run that algorithm and then output $x$. $\;$

Comment: On this wiki page there is no $x$. There are only columns for $s_i$ and $t_i$

Comment: See "..., that is integers x and y such that" and the equation immediately after that quote. $\;$

Comment: What is the $x = $ in the example they gave on the wiki page with 240 and 46?

Comment: $x$ is $-9$. $\;$

Comment: Ok I get it now. One more question. What is $y$?

Comment: $y$ is 47. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Write a full fledged answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compute the inverse of $a$ modulo $n$, use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find the GCD of $a$ and $n$ (which should be 1), together with coefficients $x,y$ such that $ax + ny = 1$. The inverse of $a$ modulo $n$ is thus $x$.

The extended Euclidean algorithm gives a constructive proof of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which states that for all integers $a,b$ there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$. A different proof shows that the minimal positive value of $ax+by$ (over all $x,y$) is $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$.

The extended Euclidean algorithm works in greater generality, for any [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain). An important example is the ring of polynomials over a field.